# Linux date objects behaving differently when hour/minute/second are specified

Tags: linux, bash, datetime

Why does adding one day work differently with the variables `$d` and `$dt` below?

Linux version: CentOS 6.8

If there is some kind of hidden timezone conversion going on with `$dt` but not with `$d`? If so, how do I suppress it?

```
d="2019-04-01"
dt="2019-04-01 01:00:00"
date --date="$d +1 days" +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

Output: 2019-04-02

```
date --date="$dt +1 days" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Output: 2019-04-01 17:00:00

Comment: You are unintentionally specifying a time zone in offset notation, like in `2019-04-01T01:00:00+01:00`

Comment: @jhnc I'm getting the same output for `2019-04-01 01:00:00 +1 days` as for `2019-04-01 01:00:00 UTC+1` and `2019-04-01 01:00:00 CET`, and similarly `+2 days` = `UTC+2` = `CEST`

Comment: my testing was flawed. I think you're right. stick a `z` after the seconds and it works properly. (`2019-04-02 01:00:00 +50 days` vs `2019-04-02 01:00:00z +50 days`)

Answer (score 1):

Just so this question is answered (I couldn't find a duplicate) it was pointed out in the comments that the `+1` in `+1 days` was being interpreted as a UTC offset appended to the date.

The solution is to terminate the date string with a time zone specifier such as `Z` or `UTC` so it's recognized as a complete date.

See `info '(coreutils) date invocation'` for more details on date specifications.